# What is causing this type error in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

```
type expr = NUM of int
        | PLUS of expr * expr
        | MINUS of expr * expr

let rec calc expr1 =
        match expr1 with
        | NUM i -> NUM i
        | PLUS (lexpr1, rexpr1) ->
                (match lexpr1, rexpr1 with
                | (*(NUM li1,NUM ri1) -> NUM li1+ri1*)
                | (lexpr1', rexpr1') -> PLUS (calc lexpr1', calc rexpr1'))
```

It says

> Error: This expression has type expr but an expression was expected of type int

I don't know why errors keep coming out

Answer (score 0):

Ocaml in the line

```
NUM li1+ri1
```

first creates a NUM and then tries to add ri1. But since `+` operator applies only on `int`s and not at `expr` and `int`, it throws an error.

To fix this add ints first:

```
NUM (li1+ri1)
```